# "Configure your API project" link not working

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Chrome. I have a Google account. When I click on the link 'configure your API project' in the instructions on this page...

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key

It tries to load this page: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?authuser=1

but it never returns. Any ideas how I can load this page and continue my education?

Comment: Same happens on IE 11.0.96.

Comment: did you try incognito tabs on chrome?

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Yusuf. That required me to login to my google account again but I managed to get past the problem I posted. Solved.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes this type of problems cause is cookies and incognito tabs are useful for that :)